# Failing Fast on IO [String]

Tags: haskell

Given an `IO [String]` representing a list of emails:

```
λ: let emails = return ["foo@bar.com", "bip@bap.net"] :: IO [String]
```

And a function that automatically fails to delete an email:

```
λ: let deleteEmail email = return $ Left "failed" :: IO (Either String ())
```

I then looked at how to, for each email in the list, attempt to delete each email. However, when a single email fails to delete, I'd like to stop, i.e. similar to `sequence`'s behavior.

```
λ: do { e <- emails; _ <- deleteEmail e; return e }
["foo@bar.com","bip@bap.net"]

λ: do { e <- emails; result <- deleteEmail e; return result }
Left "failed"
```

However, from looking at the first `do`'s output, when failing to delete `foo@bar.com`, the `do` continues to try to delete `bip@bap.net`.

How can I modify the above code to fail on the first email deletion failure?

Comment: In the expression `do { e <- emails; _ <- deleteEmail e; return e }`, the `Left ".."` part is never used; the IO action producing the result in `deleteEmail` is run, which is just `return`, but the value isn't used so it won't be evaluated. It is the same as `do { e <- emails; _ <- return undefined; return e }` This seems like a misunderstanding of how monads "compose".

Comment: Another thing is that `e` doesn't actually refer to a single email, but to the whole list of them. (Only in the list monad do lists get "split" automatically when using `<-`.) So if you'd given `deleteEmail` the intended type signature you'd have got a type error from both do expressions.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a number of options, but I'd look at three of them, in my order of preference here.

- Use `EitherT` transformer over `IO` instead of `IO (Either a)` (you'll need to install `either` package)
- Use `fail` from `Monad` instance of `IO`.
- `throw` an exception.

Comment: You can use `ExceptT` in transformers (which is more likely to be a dependency already) instead of `EitherT`.

Comment: Hi Bartek - could you please supplement your answers with some code examples? I'm not familiar with monad transformers. Thanks **edit** - the third option, `throw an exception` is not idiomatic, is it?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I certainly prefer `ExceptT` to `throwIO` (don't use `throw` inside `IO`!); however there are times when exceptions are just what the doctor ordered, so I don't think I would endorse "`throwIO` is not idiomatic". I might be convinced to endorse "`throw` is not idiomatic".

Comment: Last time I've checked there were at least 7 ways to handle errors in Haskell and I don't know if any of them was considered "non-idiomatic"

Comment: `fail` in the `IO` monad also ends up throwing an exception, and is somewhat deprecated for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer indicates you can use the `ExceptT` or `EitherT` monad transformers. `ExceptT` represents an `Either` along with an underlying monad (IO in this case) in which you can evaluate actions using `lift`. Since `EihterT` forms a monad (and therefore applicative) you can use `sequence_` to combine the deletions of all emails and fail on the first failure e.g.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.Foldable (sequence_)

getEmails :: IO [String]
getEmails = return ["foo@bar.com", "bip@bap.net", "something@example.com"]

deleteEmail :: String -> ExceptT String IO ()
deleteEmail email = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn ("Deleting " ++ email)
  if (isPrefixOf "bip" email)
     then throwE email
     else return ()

deleteAllEmails :: [String] -> ExceptT String IO ()
deleteAllEmails = sequence_ . map deleteEmail 

doDelete :: [String] -> IO ()
doDelete emails = do
  e <- runExceptT $ deleteAllEmails emails
  case e of
    Left err -> putStrLn $ "Failed: " ++ err
    Right _ -> putStrLn "success!"
```

You might also want to consider using `Maybe String` instead of `Either String ()` and the corresponding `MaybeT` transformer.

Comment: my only reason for using `Either ... ()` is that `...` can be an ADT. Using `Maybe String`'s `Nothing` case may possibly not provide the amount of meaning as `Either` (unless `Either` is used with it). Note - I know that I used `String`, which isn't an ADT, though.